# fill iphone screen with view called from subview

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl on my View in my app. The scrollview contains 2 viewcontrollers (page1 and page2) and each page is managed in a separate class and has a button's list.

My problem is that I want to open a new controller when I touch up inside one button from page1, for example, and the new viewcontroller is shown as a subview of scrollview (is the new page1), so the pagecontrol and page2 is being shown too and the scroll still works.

It's normal because I do this in my page1 code:

```
void HandleTouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyNewController mnc = new MyNewController();
    this.View.AddSubview(mnc.View);
}
```

So my question is..

How can I set the controller called to fill the screen? Is possible to fill the screen with a view called from a subview?

**Edited:**

[image: This is page1]  [image: This is the new controller as page1, not as a new view controller filling the screen]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved calling top navigation controller from my app delegate.

```
    void HandleTouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clases viewClases = new Clases();

        AppDelegate del = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
        del._navController.SetNavigationBarHidden(false, true);
        del._navController.PushViewController(viewClases, false);

    }
```

More information on this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142134/accessing-a-top-navigation-controller-from-a-subview-navigation-controller)

Answer (score 1):

#### Using Storyboards

I would recommend using the StoryBoard editor to design your UI. Control-drag from your button to your MyNewController.  Select **modal** for the Action Segue.

#### Using Code

```
void HandleTouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool animated = true;
    NSAction completionHandler = null;
    MyNewController mnc = new MyNewController();
    PresentViewController(mnc, animated, completionHandler);
}
```

#### Dismissing

In either case, when you want to dismiss the modal view call `DismissViewController` from MyNewController.

```
bool animated = true;
NSAction completionHandler = null;
DismissViewController(animated, completionHandler);
```

Comment: I prefer not using storyboard because it causes problems with custom controllers as I want. I tried your Code but it presents the newcontroller as a controller contained in scrollview as you see in edited post

Comment: That surprises me; I thought iPhone always presented modal view controllers as full screen... (On iPad you could set mnc.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen) I suppose you could try ParentViewController.PresentViewController(...).